# How to add extension attributes to a csr generated by bouncycastle (1.5.1)

Tags: bouncycastle, csr

Q1: Is there a way to add custom extention attributes (e.g. CertificatePolicies, ExtemdedKeyUsage, KeyUsage, Admission,...) to an CSR generated with bouncyCastle 1.5.1?

Q2: Will a CA take extention attributes into account at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: See [Adding attributes to certificate request, java + bouncycastle 1.48](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398955/adding-attributes-to-certificate-request-java-bouncycastle-1-48)

Q2: This may depend on the CA, but I think the answer is usually "no". Certainly no CA will just copy CertificatePolicies, KeyUsage or ExtendedKeyUsage from your CSR to the certificate, as that would be horribly insecure.